# Como generar PDF en base a otro archivo ya existente con jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

Como puedo utilizar un archivo que ya existe como base para poder crear mi archivo pdf con `jsPDF`, actualmente genero uno de la nada pero quisiera usar una plantilla que ya tengo generada como base y ya solo mostrar en ese la informacion.

Actualmente mi codigo se ve de esta manera

`DownloadPDF`

```
      $('#downloadPdfButton').click(function(event) {
        // Crear un nuevo documento PDF
        let pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm', [480, 210]);

        pdf.setFontSize(20);
        pdf.text(15, 15, "Discrepancy age by planner");

        const canvas = document.getElementById('timeBar');
        const canop = document.getElementById('openChart');
        const timetable = document.getElementById('timetable');
        const tabledemo2 = document.getElementById('tabledemo2');

        // Crear imágenes a partir de los canvas
        const canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);
        const canvasImageOp = canop.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 5);

        // Configurar el fondo blanco para las tablas antes de capturar su contenido
        tabledemo2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        timetable.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

        // Capturar el contenido de las tablas HTML utilizando html2canvas
        html2canvas(tabledemo2).then(function(tabledemo2Canvas) {
          const tabledemo2Image = tabledemo2Canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);

          html2canvas(timetable).then(function(timetableCanvas) {
            const timetableImage = timetableCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 5);

            // Restaurar el fondo original de las tablas
            tabledemo2.style.backgroundColor = '';
            timetable.style.backgroundColor = '';

            // Agregar las imágenes y las tablas al PDF
            pdf.addImage(canvasImage, 'JPEG', 15, 50, 269, 106); // Imagen a un costado de la timetable
            pdf.addImage(timetableImage, 'JPEG', 315, 35, 90, 135); // Tabla 'timetable' al lado de 'canvasImage'
            pdf.addPage(); // Salto de página
            pdf.addImage(canvasImageOp, 'JPEG', 15, 50, 270, 110); // Imagen a un costado de la tabla 'tabledemo2'
            pdf.addImage(tabledemo2Image, 'JPEG', 350, 80, 75, 70); // Tabla 'tabledemo2' al lado de 'canvasImageOp'

            // Configurar el marco de color para el texto
            pdf.setDrawColor(255, 0, 0); // Color del marco (rojo)
            pdf.setFillColor(255, 255, 255); // Color del fondo (blanco)
            pdf.rect(15, 29, 445, 10, 'FD'); // Rectángulo con marco y fondo

            pdf.setFontSize(20);
            pdf.setTextColor(255, 0, 0); // Color del texto (rojo)
            pdf.text(20, 36, "Opened discrepancies by supplier");

            // Guardar el PDF con las imágenes y las tablas
            pdf.save('Discrepancias.pdf');
          });
        });
      });
```